# Closing tabs on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to made a tab function on my website and I would like to have that tabs responsive. So I made code like this:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

/* Style the close button */
.topright {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.topright:hover {color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Now I am stacked with two things,

- first is that I would like tabs to close on click on title (London,
  Paris, Tokyo), and then to remove active class from that title when
  it is clicked.
- And second, I would like to have this responsive with two tabs in
  row, third one is going in second row, and then on click to open right
  below tab that is clicked, and to push the third one down.

Any hint will help, thanks in advance

Comment: not quite understand your second question mate

Comment: I don't understand it either.. You can't show 2 tabs in a row, because the logic imposes you only show the `active` one.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear.My plan is to have six tabs with six titles (london, paris..). On certain break point (ex. less then 1200px) six tabs will be in two rows (3 by row). When I click on tab, now it is opened bellow second row of titles, and I would like to be opened bellow first row of titles, and second row should be pushed down.

Comment: I don't think you can because you can't just rearrange elements according to screen width with CSS only. Did you considered minifying the titles into a dropdown menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you issue no. 1, you can just change from "openCity" to "toggleCity", by checking if the current city is shown -> then you hide, otherwise you show it.

```js
function toggleCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
   
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    var prev_state_display = document.getElementById(cityName).style.display;
    
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    
    if( prev_state_display === "none"){
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "none";
        evt.currentTarget.className.replace(" active", "");
    }
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

/* Style the close button */
.topright {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.topright:hover {color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="toggleCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="toggleCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="toggleCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="toggleCity(event, 'London')" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="toggleCity(event, 'Paris')" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="toggleCity(event, 'Tokyo')" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

For what concern your issue no. 2, here you can see a sample written in "bad code" just to put you on the right track. If you resize the iframe container width, it will behave like you asked..

It needs a good review though. [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/u6nmbovk/15/)

The code is splitted in two parts, but shown as a single with the help of floats.. 
Check [`@media`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) at bottom of CSS code.

PS I used some jquery code since I was getting some error for the `toggleCity` function not being defined..

**The jQuery way**

Here is how you can do that with jQuery. Just add CSS style as follows

`.tabcontent.active {display: block}`

Also add HTML5 `data` attribute to `.tablinks` and here is the script

```
$('.tablinks').on('click', function(){
  let target_id = $(this).data('target');
  $('.tablinks, .tabcontent').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(target_id).addClass('active');
});
$('.close-tab').on('click', function(){
  $('.tablinks, .tabcontent').removeClass('active');
});

$("#defaultOpen").click();
```

--> [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pnL4ugk/7/)

Comment: This is great, thanks. Can you pleas just help me with one more thing. How can I change that active class once I click on x for closing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That can be one approach, not clean one, but it can be good. Only thing that I can not see is how when I click on x to close, to remove active class from tab title. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Check edited post. You should replace the `onClick` function for the X span.

Comment: If you want, I can also show you how to do this with jQuery. Far less code rows.